# Format date from json with Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, date, formatting

I'm trying to write a autocomplete for TMDb, but I can't figure out how to format the date.

The TMDB API returns a date like `2001-12-19`. I want to display the data like `Title (Year)`.

I've tried to fiddle around and get the date with jQuery like http://jsfiddle.net/XHyy3/.

My script:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    function log( message ) {
      $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=myapikey",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          data: {
            query: request.term
          },
          success: function( data ) {
            response( $.map( data.results, function( item ) {
              return {
                label: item.title + " (" + item.release_date + ")",
                value: item.title,
                name: item.id
              }
            }));
          }
        });
      },
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
    $("input#city").val(ui.item.name);
    $('input[name="q"]').attr('name', 'id');
    $('input[id="film"]').click();
      },
      open: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
      },
      close: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
      }
    });
   });
 </script>
```

`item.release_date` contains the date, e.g `2001-12-19`.

Comment: It looks like you found a solution in your jsfiddle. Are you just wondering if there's a better way? You could shorten it to `item.release_date.split('-')[0]`.

Comment: I found out how to do it in jsfiddle indeed, but I can't get it working in the code above.
I'm pretty new to jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everything else is working fine, just change this line:

```
label: item.title + " (" + item.release_date + ")",
```

To this:

```
label: item.title + " (" + item.release_date.split('-')[0] + ")",
```